# C#: What encoding is the file in when mixing encodings?

Tags: c#, pdf, encoding

I  need to send a file to mainframe.
The file contains two types of data: A header record and a pdf.
It looks a bit like this:

***SEP***Some data***SEP***... pdf data ...

The header is encoded in IBM500 (EBCDIC) and the pdf as "iso-8859-1".

This file is processed by another system which sends it to the mainframe.
The system must be configured and one of the parameter is the encoding of the source file which is the file I create.

What is the actual encoding of the file when you're mixing encodings?

Comment: Well it's not a text file with a single encoding, at that point... if the file processor tries to read it as if it *is* just text, it will probably lose data. (I generally regard PDFs as binary data rather than plain text, to start with...)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Does it means the system, which transfers the file, should read the file as binary and not using some kind of encoding (UTF8, ANSI...)?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: *the pdf as "iso-8859-1"* - this is an error; PDFs are binaries, not text files serialized with an encoding.